# ATMEGA 328 TQFP32-08 Vs atmega 48 TQFP

Tags: atmega

what is the difference between ATMEGA328 TQFP32-08 and Atmega48 TQFP ?
does he share the same pins ?

I'm a bit confused,  :
https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48P-1315288.pdf

Comment: The 328 is more recent with more resources.  Beyond that this is "too broad"

Answer (score 2):

Per the datasheet:

The ATmega48A/PA/88A/PA/168A/PA/328/P differ only in memory sizes, boot loader support, and interrupt vector sizes:
Device Flash EEPROM RAM Interrupt Vector Size

ATmega48A 4KBytes 256Bytes 512Bytes 1 instruction word/vector

ATmega48PA 4KBytes 256Bytes 512Bytes 1 instruction word/vector

ATmega88A 8KBytes 512Bytes 1KBytes 1 instruction word/vector

ATmega88PA 8KBytes 512Bytes 1KBytes 1 instruction word/vector

ATmega168A 16KBytes 512Bytes 1KBytes 2 instruction words/vector

ATmega168PA 16KBytes 512Bytes 1KBytes 2 instruction words/vector

ATmega328 32KBytes 1KBytes 2KBytes 2 instruction words/vector

ATmega328P 32KBytes 1KBytes 2KBytes 2 instruction words/vector

Figure 1-1. Pinout ATmega48A/PA/88A/PA/168A/PA/328/P  shows they have the same pinout.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... Very clear